# PhpStorm specify run configuration for view in browser

Tags: phpstorm

So I have a .php file in a my project called test.php. When I go to View -> Open in Browser the browser will open the file with a url of `http://localhost:63342/project_name/test.php`.

And I will get a "Bad Gateway' message in the browser. I have apache running on port 80, and if I go to `http://localhost/~collin/project_name/test.php` things will work as intended. I know I can set up a run configuration which will open the index of my project every time I click run, but how do I set things up so that when I click View -> Open in Browser it will open up the file in the correct location?

I have been going through the jet brains docs and can't seem to find an article addressing this.

(just incase it's relevant I'm running os x)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Settings (Preferences on Mac) | Deployment`

- Create entry of correct type
- Enter the website's root URL (`http://localhost/~collin/project_name/` as I understand)
- **Mark it as Default** for this project.